# php framework to serve android app

Tags: php, android, frameworks

I'm developing android app. It's some sort of social network. Where user can add friend and some few stuff. I've been working on php for quite a time now. But android is **totally new** for me. The app will be served by a web service. 
My android skill are not good. So total time I spend on working on android part is more. So I'm thinking is there any framework that can be used to serve my application. With this I can reduce time to implement web service. I know some of framework but as I have not worked with them, I don't know how much they can be extended to fit in my need. **OR** should I implement it by my own without any framework ?

All the suggestions, advises will be extremely helpful.

Comment: Im pretty sure there is no "Framework" for the android SDK, no wait the SDK is a java framework. Suggest you look at some java tutorials to get the basic syntax then have a look at the tutorials on youtube, theres a guy called bucky from the new boston that basicly implements every possible feature of the SDK into 200 episodes http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SUOWNXGRc6g&feature=BFa&list=PL34F010EEF9D45FB8&lf=BFa

Comment: @LawrenceCherone - many thanks for link. This will surely help me in android. But I want to know about php frameworks that can be used easily to send json, xml response to android app. As I don't need to work on any html,css,javascript; I want to skip that part totally to reduce workload of processing request and simply output json or xml. thanks again.

Comment: Though not related to web service framework question, you can develop your android application in javascript using titanium http://www.appcelerator.com/. This can reduce your development a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my opinion you should definitely go with a framework, so you can concentrate more on developing the Android app.

Important is, that you choose your backend framework wisley. So it should be a lightweight and/or RAD (Rapid Application Development) framework, which enables you to use code generation for common patterns to get startet very fast.

I can recommend Ruby on Rails. If you want to stick with PHP, then my recommandation would be [Symfony 2](http://symfony.com/doc/current/) or [Kohana](http://kohanaframework.org/). Using those frameworks, you should concept and implement an API, preferably [RESTful](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer), which provides your Android application with data and can be used later on for all other kind of mobile apps or third party applications.

If you go with [Symfony 2](http://symfony.com/doc/current/) you can have a look for the [FOSRestBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle) - a bundle which provides tools to create a RESTful API.

Further on, Symfony 2 comes with a very good [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/) - including a getting started section, as well as a cookbook.

So,... happy coding. :)

Comment: thanks for response. I have to look in depth for both before using. Implementing API is the thing I am looking forward. :D

Answer (score 2):

I don't think a framework is really needed here. An efficient way to communicate between your server and Android is through the JSON data format. It's smaller than XML, but it's just as easy to use.

For example, to request the list of friends, you could send a request like this:

```
http://www.example.com/android.php?do=friends
```

And send your authentication cookies just like with the desktop site. A response would look like this:

```
{
    "friends": [
        {
            "name": "John Lua",
            "age": 19,
            "friends_since": 32423434
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

In the production version, you can of course leave out the indentation and other spacing.

It is trivial to generate this output in PHP, but if you want, you can use a function like this: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Parsing it again in Java (on Android) can be done with a library: http://json.org/java/

You would request this response with a normal web request in Java. You can find information on web requests with cookies here: http://www.hccp.org/java-net-cookie-how-to.html

Serverside, you would handle Android clients just like desktop clients, only with a different output format.

Comment: thanks for response. If I don't use any framework than I have to write code for everything like database connection, handling connection fails, generating queries according to request, handling query-data errors, some validations if push-pop from database fails,managing headers (as this service is open on cloud,I want to use custom headers to differentiate between my app and other referrers and restricting access). I think framework can reduce my time doing this a little bit to focus myself on android app part.